# Why is this if statement failing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I'm having problems comparing strings in an if statement. This is what I have:

```
declare @old varchar(max), @manual varchar(max)
set @old = (select ruledef from roolz where ruleid = 1234)
set @manual = 'String responseDate = subject.getField("Response Due Date");' + char(10)
  + 'if (responseDate != null && responseDate .trim().length() > 0) {' + char(10)
  + ' Map params = new HashMap();' + char(10)
  + ' params.put("Response Due Date",responseDate);' + char(10) + char(10) +
  + 'ruleUtil.launchActivity(subject,"PCT-RESP",params,"Launch_PCTRESP",false);' + char(10)
  + char(10) + '}' + char(10)
print @manual
print @old
--if (@old like '%' + @manual + '%')
if (@old = @manual)
begin
  print 1;
end
```

When I run this it prints out the following showing that `@old` and `@manual` are the same:

```
String responseDate = subject.getField("Response Due Date");

if (responseDate != null && responseDate .trim().length() > 0) {
    Map params = new HashMap();
    params.put("Response Due Date",responseDate);

    ruleUtil.launchActivity(subject,"PCT-RESP",params,"Launch_PCTRESP",false);
}

String responseDate = subject.getField("Response Due Date");

if (responseDate != null && responseDate .trim().length() > 0) {
    Map params = new HashMap();
    params.put("Response Due Date",responseDate);

    ruleUtil.launchActivity(subject,"PCT-RESP",params,"Launch_PCTRESP",false);
}
```

But it does not print 1 meaning the if statement failed. I also tried

```
if (@old like '%' + @manual + '%')
```

and it still does not print 1.

Can anyone tell me why this if statement is failing?

Comment: All it takes is one character to be different - it could be a non-printing character (`LF` vs `CR/LF`?) or a character that _looks_ like a space in both strings but isn't.  I would loop character-by-character until it finds a difference.

Comment: The strings as written here really are the same; I checked. Perhaps something was lost when they were pasted to Stack Overflow. Maybe try different combinations of line breaks and carriage returns (`char(10)` and `char(13)`)?

Comment: Did you check for possible trailing white spaces?

Comment: Are they the same length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution. I was taking into consideration line breaks but I was not taking into consideration tab characters. I escaped line breaks and tab characters and its working as it should. Thanks to @D Stanley for pointing me in the direction of thinking about other characters.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why the test is failing, but rather than looking at it and being stumped, You could change your IF test to dig out why the one you've got isnt working:

```
if (@old = @manual) print 1;      --this one obviously won't happen
if (substring(@old, 1, 100) = substring(@manual, 1, 100)) print 2;
if (len(@old) = len(@manual) print 3;
if (ltrim(rtrim(@old)) = ltrim(rtrim(@manual))) print 4;
etc
```